# iOS - Switch WiFi networks programmatically - Jailbroken

Tags: ios, wifi, jailbreak

I am well aware that using private APIs to access network info will get your app rejected.

However, assuming that I have a jailbroken device, is it possible to programmatically switch between two WiFi networks?

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna have to use [MobileApple80211](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Apple80211Functions) framework.

For how to use this framework [stumbler](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Stumbler) is probably best learning tool - source code.

It's not built as an XCode project though, so prepare for some tweaking.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to show how to connect to a network.

Comment: True - it's more of an example of where to look. You're gonna have to dig into [private API's](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks). AirTraffic.framework could also seem interesting for your task, for example.